# Ruby on Rails nested routes with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have two models:

Reservation:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car_emission
end
```

CarEmission:

```
class CarEmission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

and following routes:

```
resources :reservations do 
  resources :car_emissions
end
```

Now when I want to create new car_emission i must visit url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/reservations/1/car_emissions/new
```

and when i want to edit I must visit:

```
http://localhost:3000/reservations/1/car_emissions/1/edit
```

Is there anyway to change routes that my car_emission edit link will look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/reservations/1/car_emission
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to do several things:

```
1. Create singular resource
2. Change the `edit` path for your controller
```

---

[**Singular Resource**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

As suggested by `@sreekanthGS`, you'll firstly be best creating a singular resource. This works in the same way as the `resources` method, except it treats your route as a single record; doing away with the `index` route etc:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reservations do
    resource :car_emission # -> localhost:3000/reservations/1/car_emission
end
```

---

**Edit**

This will create a set of RESTful routes for your `car_emission` , but it will still take you to the `car_emissions#show` action when you hit the "naked" link

You'll be best doing this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reservations do
    resource :car_emission, except: :show, path_names: { edit: "" }
end
```

This will take you to the `edit` action when you hit the "naked" link

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
resources :reservations do 
  resource :car_emissions
end
```

There is something called Singular Resources:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

***Quoted:***

Section: **2.5 Singular Resources**

Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action:

```
get 'profile', to: 'users#show'
```

Passing a String to get will expect a controller#action format, while passing a Symbol will map directly to an action:

```
get 'profile', to: :show
```

This resourceful route:

```
resource :geocoder
```

creates six different routes in your application, all mapping to the Geocoders controller.

Answer (score 1):

[`shallow: true`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) might be what you want

```
resources :reservations, shallow: true do 
  resources :car_emissions
end
```

`shallow: true`will nest `index`, `create` and `new` actions of `:car_emissions` inside the `:reservations`. `update` action will  not be nested inside.

This will give you routes that look like this:

```
GET  /reservations/:reservation_id/car_emissions(.:format)   caremissions#index
POST     /reservations/:reservation_id/car_emissions(.:format)   caremissions#create
GET  /reservations/:reservation_id/car_emission/new(.:format) caremissions#new

GET  /reservations/:id/edit(.:format)    reservations#edit
PATCH    /reservations/:id(.:format)     reservations#update
PUT  /reservations/:id(.:format)     reservations#update
DELETE   /reservations/:id(.:format)     reservations#destroy
GET  /reservations/:id(.:format)     reservations#show
```

Answer (score 1):

Link of this type

```
http://localhost:3000/reservations/1/car_emission
```

is given to show car emissions for restful resources and so using it for simple edit like the one you used above may clash with restful resources.

You may optionally make a separate Singular resource and and direct it to your desired route.